# Display message when user tries to click after max date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

On my datepicker I have to set a max date on a specific date. However, having a max date isn't going to make any sense for the users (but for now I have to restrict them on that).

So, for not confusing users, I want to display a message, when they will try to navigate or click after that date, for why they can't select it.

Datepicker doesn't seem to provide any onclick event.
How I could catch users clicks on the navigation or the disabled dates and show them a message if the date is later than the max date?

Comment: Simply disable the dates you don't want them to click. See https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Answer (score 1):

Disabled dates (those outside the min/max) get the class ui-state-disabled added to them by the datepicker. Bind the click event to that class and set an alert.

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-state-disabled', function () {
    alert('Invalid date')
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pms6kj1h/)**

Comment: That was my initial idea, but it works the same for both before minDate and after maxDate. The message has to be specific for after the max date. Any chance I could get the date the user tried to click?

Comment: I found my way around, working with the data-month attribute of the calendar's td(s). Thanks anyway for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to do this by expanding a bit on j08681 suggestion above.

The Calendar comes with the html5 data- attribute...
So, being a little lucky, as the max date is 2 days before the end of a month - I am grabbing the **`data-month`** value of the previous **`td`** in the calendar with the jQuery `.data()`, like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-state-disabled', function () {
    if ($(this).prev().data('month') === 3) alert ('Invalid');
})
```

So, when a user clicks on any .ui-state-disabled, I will check if previous day td has data-month = 3. If yes it means user clicked on after Max Date. That will be only true for the 31st day, which is the first disabled day after my maxDate.
I have a similar one, listening on the **`.ui-datepicker-next.ui-state-disabled`**, so users can't proceed to the next month and they also get my message.